# Angular 4 date and time picker

Tags: angular

Is there any third party library in angular 4?
I want to pick the date first and then the time.

There are libraries which pick either one of these. I want to select both.
Its for the picking date and time.

Comment: I like ng-bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look ng-pick-datetime, it's easy to use and implement.
Its responsive and work on both desktops and mobiles.

Take a look at the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime) for this Date Time Picker.

Answer (score 1):

try this.
https://github.com/nkalinov/ng2-datetime

here is a working demo as well.
https://nkalinov.github.io/ng2-datetime/

### Instructions

npm install --save ng2-datetime

1)import some way or another the required dependencies in the following order:

Bootstrap CSS
jQuery
bootstrap-timepicker + bootstrap-datepicker

2) `import { NKDatetimeModule } from 'ng2-datetime/ng2-datetime';`

3) Add it to your app module's imports property

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [NKDatetimeModule, ...],
    ...
})
```

4) Use it: `<datetime [(ngModel)]="date"></datetime>`

Answer (score -1):

PrimeNG got a Timepicker/Calendar which is able to Pick Date and Time in one Step.

[PrimeNG Calendar](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar)(Its the "Time" example)